# Finding the right user-agent for a specific website

Tags: node.js, http, url, user-agent, preview

I am using `link-preview-js` NPM Package to fetch a website's title, description and image. However, I am not receiving correct data for a specific website.

Website: https://www.britishcouncil.pk/exam/school/your-world

Result I am getting:

```
{
    url: 'https://www.britishcouncil.pk/exam/school/your-world',
    title: 'Access Denied',
    siteName: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    mediaType: 'website',
    contentType: 'text/html',
    images: [],
    videos: [],
    favicons: [ 'https://www.britishcouncil.pk/favicon.ico' ]
}
```

I need to find the right user-agent which would fetch correct data. I tried googlebot, Twitterbot and facebookexternalhit without success. How do I get correct data?

The correct data would have "Your World - Your Opportunity | British Council" as Title.

Code:

```
exports.fetchLinkPreview = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, async () => {
        try {
            const link = req.query.link;
            const { getLinkPreview } = require('link-preview-js');
            const linkResult = await getLinkPreview(link, {
                imagesPropertyType: "og",
                headers: {
                    "user-agent": "googlebot"
                },
                timeout: 10000
            })
            return res.send({ error: false, message: linkResult });

        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error", e)
            res.send({ error: true, message: "Incorrect link" })
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of latest user-agents: https://whatmyuseragent.com/engines

The first one worked for me. `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; vivo 1904; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Mobile Safari/537.36 VivoBrowser/8.7.0.1`